# Linq Merge lists

Tags: c#, linq

My class:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    }
```

I've got `IEnumerable<Foo>`. I would like get `List<Foo>` grouping by A, and get Bars list, which contais all elements at Bars for group.

So final Foo.Bars should contains all elements of Bar at group

Is it possible with linq?

Comment: Aren't the `Foos` in your source `IEnumerable<Foo>` already that way?  You source must be of a different type, right?  What does the source actually look like?

Comment: No i would like get collection of the same type, but with merging lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var result = foos.GroupBy(f => f.A)
                 .SelectMany(grp => grp.Select(f => f.Bars));
```

As Rawling has mentioned, this returns not an `IEnumerable<Foo>`, so try this:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> result = 
            foos.GroupBy(f => f.A)
            .Select(grp => new Foo() { 
                A = grp.Key,
                Bars = grp.SelectMany(ff => ff.Bars).Distinct().ToList()
            });
```

I'm not sure whether you want a distinct list of `Bars` or not. Note that you may need to override `Equals`  and `GetHashCode` in class `Bar`.

Comment: This seems like what he might be looking for, but I'm still confused about the actual source.

Comment: This won't return a `List<Foo>`.