# Combining lists in linq

Tags: c#, linq

in linq, is it possible to combine many lists (of the same type), such that two lists,

list 1 = {a,b,c} and list 2 = {x,y,z}

turns into {[1,a] , [1,b] , [1,c] , [2,x] , [2,y] , [2,z] }

where [] represents a pair containing a "list identifier"

The problem is from having decks of arbitrary cards, where each deck is a list in a collection of lists.

I'm trying to create a query such that I can select only cards in a certain deck, or cards similar to 2 or more decks.

This is probably a duplicate question, but I don't know how to search for the question further then I already have.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051299/linq-merge-lists

Comment: what does it mean `{[1,a] , [1,b] , [1,c] , [2,x] , [2,y] , [2,z] }`?

Comment: @jayram we have the automatic related list, don't spam links. if you think one is actually a dupe, mark it as such (or say so, if you don't have enough rep for that)

Comment: @Jayram None of those questions are the same as this question. Please stahp.

Comment: have a look at the `Tuple<int,int>` class, you can then maintain a `List` of Tuples.

Comment: Wow, honestly wasn't expecting so many answers, having difficulty working out which is the best method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the lists like:

```
var first = new List<string> {"a","b","c"};
var second = new List<string> {"x","y","z"};

var merged = first.Select(item => new { ListIndex = 1, Value = item}).ToList();
merged.AddRange(second.Select(item => new { ListIndex = 2, Value = item});

//or use concat
var merged = first.Select(item => new { ListIndex = 1, Value = item});
    .Concat(second.Select(item => new { ListIndex = 2, Value = item});
```

Alternatively if you have the sources in something like:

```
List<List<string>> lists = new List<List<string>>
                           {
                              new List<string> {"a","b","c"},
                              new List<string> {"x","y","z"}
                           };
```

you can do:

```
var merged = lists.SelectMany((item, index) => 
                         item.Select(s => new { ListIndex = index, Value = s}));
```

Note that this will produce a 0-based list, so if you really need a 1-base list, just do `ListIndex = index +1`.

Also, if you will use this a lot, I would create it as an specific entity, something like

```
struct ListIdentValue
{
   public int ListIndex {get; private set;}
   public string Value {get; private set;}

   public ListIdentValue(int listIndex, string value) {...}
}
```

Comment: accepted this answer as the answer as it contained the most information, in reality many of these answers would work for various different reasons, and I had much difficulty in choosing which of these to accept.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<List<int>> lists;

var combined = lists.Select((l, idx) => new { List = l, Idx = idx })
    .SelectMany(p => p.List.Select(i => Tuple.Create(p.Idx + 1, i)));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var list1 = new List<string>() {a,b,c};
var list2 = new List<string>() {x,y,z};

var combined = list1.Select(x => new { id = 1, v = x }).Concat(list2.Select(x => new { id = 2, v = x }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally I'd suggest [Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) for combining multiple lists, however you seem to actually want to concatenate multiple lists with a list counter.

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<int,T>> Combine<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] lists) {
  return lists.Select((x,i) => x.Select(y => Tuple.Create(i+1,y))).SelectMany (l =>l);
}
```

**UPDATE** 
  *Completely missed that SelectMany has the index option so the above code can be written as*

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<int,T>> Combine<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] lists) {
  return lists.SelectMany((x,i) => x.Select(y => Tuple.Create(i+1,y)));
}
```

Then you can do

```
 var list1 = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
 var list2 = new List<string> { "x", "y", "z" };
 var combined = Combine(list1,list2);
```

Combined will be enumerable of tuples, with `Item1` being the list index identifier (starting at 1) and `Item2` being the value.

This method will handle multiple lists so you could just as easily call it with:

```
var list3 = new List<string> { "f", "g" };
var combined =  Combine(list1,list2,list3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx)

```
new[] {'a','b','c'}
.Select(v=>new Tuple<int,char>(1, v))
.Concat(
    new[] {'x','y','z'}.Select(v=>new Tuple<int,char>(2, v))
)
```

Comment: Isn't the general practice to use `Tuple.Create` rather than the constructor on the generic class?

Comment: What is the problem in using the constructor here, @BobVale? See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181.aspx they are equivalent.

Comment: `new Tuple` forces you to be explicit about the types, `Tuple.Create` can infer them, so both have usage scenarios where one is more suitable than the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string[] a = { "a", "b", "c" };
    string[] b = { "x", "z", "y" };


    var t =
    (
    from ai in a
    select new { listNo = 1, Item = ai }
    ).Union
    (
    from bi in b
    select new { listNo = 2, Item = bi }
        );
```

or

```
var t =
        (
        from ai in a
        select new object[] { 1, ai }
        ).Union
        (
        from bi in b
        select new object[] { 2, bi }
            );
```